# SockJS and meteor: what if load balancer do not support sticky sessions?

Tags: meteor, load-balancing, sockjs

I'm exploring balancing options for Meteor. [This](http://meteorhacks.com/load-balancing-your-meteor-app.html) article looks very cool and it says that the following should be supported to load balance Meteor:

1. Mongo optailing. Otherwise, it may take up to ten seconds for one instance of Meteor to get updates from the another, because polling Mongo driver will be used, which polls-and-diffs DB each ten seconds.
2. Websocket. It's clear too - otherwise clients will fallback to HTTP and long-polling, which will work, but it's not as cool as Websocket.
3. Sticky sessions 'which are required by SockJS'. Here the question comes:

As I understood, 'sticky sessions support' is something that assign one client to the same server during his session. Is it essential? What may happen if I don't configure sticky sessions at all?

Here's what I came up to by myself:

1. Because Meteor stores all data sent to client in memory, if client connects to X servers, then X times more memory will be consumed
2. Some minor (or major, if there are no oplog) lag may appear for the same user in, say, different tabs or windows, which may be surprising.
3. If SockJS reconnects and wants some data to persist across reconnections, it gonna have a bad time. I'm not sure about how SockJS works, is this point valid?

What bad can happen? These three points doesn't look very bad: data is valid, available, may be at a cost of extra memory consumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Basics

Sticky Sessions are required to ensure that the browser's in memory session can be managed correctly by the server.

First let me explain why you need sticky sessions:

Each publish that uses an ordinary publish cursor keeps track of whatever collections the client may have, so when something changes it knows what to send down back to the client. This would apply to every Meteor app if it needs a DDP connection. This is the case with websockets and sockjs

Additionally there may be other client session state stored in variables but those you would be edge cases (e.g you store the user's state in a variable).

The problem happens when the server disconnects and reconnects, but somehow perhaps the connection gets transferred to the other node (without re-establishing a new connection) - which has no idea about the client's data, so the behaviour could turn up a bit weird.

#### The issue with SockJS & Long Polling

With SockJS there is an additional issue. SockJS uses websocket emulation when it falls back to long polling.

With Long polling a **new** connection attempt/new http request is made **every** time new data is available.

If sticky Sessions are not enabled each of these connections will be randomly assigned to a different node/dynamo.

So you have a 50% chance (in the case its random) that the server has no idea about the client's DDP Session with *every* every time new data is available.

It would then force the client to re-negotiate a connection/ignore the clients DDP commands and you would end up getting very weird behaviour on the client.

### Half of these would be to the wrong node:

[image]

Comment: I have a clarification about SockJS' long polling: each time server (or client) transmits some data over current HTTP connection, it's re-opened to extend its lifetime and ensure that no intermediate proxy will close it after 30 seconds, am I right? This also mean that these reconnections are absolutely transparent to Meteor, which would be very unexpected if SockJS don't control to which server it connects by itself, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes these are completely transparent to meteor, SockJS handles this part as part of its websocket emulation. To meteor it just handles it as if it were a normal sockjs connection (and it wouldn't know there was any difference (unless you made it). Yes SockJS would be confused without sticky sessions. Even if it didn't lose control unexpectedly, it would have to every 30 seconds - or whenever there is new data.

Comment: Good answer.  To your question about what is bad about point #1, increased server load (mem + cpu), the goal is to be able to scale your app by adding more servers.  Without sticky sessions, you will still benefit from a redundancy aspect, but since every client will eventually connect to every server you effectively nullify your ability to scale horizontally.

Comment: If you force sockjs to only use websockets as transport and never fall back to long polling, does that remove the need for sticky sessions?